# Cannot find save handler 'redis'

Tags: php, session, azure, redis

I am running a PHP 5.4 hosted Web App on Azure. To manage session handling I have configured a Redis cache instance on Azure.

I have set the session save path & handler:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://kbcache.redis.cache.windows.net:6379?auth=***"
```

I have also configured the Redis extensions:

```
PHP_EXTENSIONS  bin\php_igbinary.dll
APPSETTING_PHP_EXTENSIONS   bin\php_igbinary.dll
PHP_EXTENSIONS02    bin\php_redis.dll
APPSETTING_PHP_EXTENSIONS02 bin\php_redis.dll
```

However when I browse to my website I receive the message:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'redis' - session
>   startup failed in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php(22) : eval()'d code
>   on line 2

What am I missing?

Comment: I dug into the PHP logs and found this error:

    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php_redis.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

I have loaded that DLL into that folder, and I have specified it in my php.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update Pre post]

When deployed PHP project, we need enable extensions on Azure. 
Please see my website folder structure:

[image]

I copied the DLL files into folder named `ext`. **And those dlls' version should be VC9 and non-thread-safe (nts) compatible.**

[image]

And I created a `extension.ini` into folder name `ini`. The content as following :

```
extension=d:\home\site\ext\php_igbinary.dll
extension=d:\home\site\ext\php_redis.dll
zend_extension=d:\home\site\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://**.redis.cache.windows.net:6379?auth=**
```

At last, I add the "PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" Configurtation Panel on Azure portal:

[image]

It works for me.

Comment: thanks for that, following that last post got it working! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I tried PHPRedis extension on my environment, it works fine.

Form your description, I think you made configuration of Redis extensions complicated.

I followed those steps:

1.Switch to `PHP version 5.4`

2.Download PHPRedis extension form this [page](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/downloads).
Since I used PHP which version is `version 5.4 TS`, I downloaded `phpredis_5.4_vc9_ts`

3.After unzipped the download file, Please copy those DLL file into your PHP `ext` folder. It seems that you need pay attention to this point.

Add this code into your `PHP.ini` file

```
extension=php_igbinary.dll
extension=php_redis.dll

session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://**.redis.cache.windows.net:6379?auth=**
```

4.Create a Page and test Redis Code:

```
$redis=new Redis();
$redis->pconnect('tcp://**.redis.cache.windows.net', 6379);
$redis->auth('**+**=');
$redis->set('key', 'hello '); 
$redis->append('key', 'world '); 
echo $redis->get('key');
```

Comment: Still not much luck, I set my PHP to 5.4, downloaded the DLL's from your link. I added the following code to my ini file:

    extension=d:\home\site\ext\php_igbinary.dll
extension=d:\home\site\ext\php_redis.dll
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://**.redis.cache.windows.net:6379?auth=**"

But I'm still getting these errors:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'd:\home\site\ext\php_igbinary.dll' - The specified module could not be found. - and the same error for the php_redis.dll file

Comment: As I'm also using Azure to host my web app I need to configure my PHP as per: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/ - but I dont believe this will make a difference

Comment: Did you use the NTS version?

Answer (score 0):

had similar issues. make sure redis dll file is there and enabled in php.ini also make sure that redis folder has full write permissions.